# Spark execution using jdbc

Tags: oracle, scala, performance, dataframe, apache-spark

In the Spark dataframe, suppose I fetch data from oracle as below.

Will the query happen completely in oracle? Assume the query is huge. Is it an overhead to oracle then? Would a better approach be to read each filtered table data in a separate dataframe and join it using spark SQL or dataframe so that a complete join will happen in Spark? Can you please help with this?

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(
url="jdbc:mysql://foo.com:1111", 
dbtable="(SELECT * FROM abc,bcd.... where abc.id= bcd.id.....) AS table1",      user="test",
password="******", 
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").load()
```

Comment: I would suggest benchmarking the query performance on oracle and then on spark by following the steps you mentioned in your question. The performance varies on various factors such as a number of records, tables how complex the query or join and many more, hence this question is very broad to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

In general, actual data movement is the most time consuming and should be avoided. So, as  general rule, you want to filter as much as possible in the JDBC source (Oracle in your case) before data are moved into your Spark environment.

Once you're ready to do some analysis in Spark, you can persist (cache) the result so as to avoid re-retrieving from Oracle every time.

That being said, @shrey-jakhmola is right, you want to benchmark for your particular circumstance. Is the Oracle environment choked somehow, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying this scenario for a small POC. Did not use this in real project. Had a doubt while writing above piece code, could not see answer from any article.

Comment: If we perform join in oracle for complex queries, it will be a costly operation in oracle. So If I bring each relevant table data (eg: 1. select * from emp where status = 'S', 2. select * from dept where dept_no=2 without joining with other tables) to separate dataframes and perform join inside spark, as you said above it will be more time consuming during data movement. Since both the above approaches are having some issue, is it better to dump all the required table data to hdfs as specific file format and spark can read from hdfs directly and process. Will it be a good approach?

Comment: Oracle is pretty good at resolving complex queries. You would have to benchmark for your scenario, but my guess is that in a real-world scenario you'll want to do the join in Oracle.

Comment: I understood Oracle can process this pretty good. But felt like rather doing this processing in Oracle, we can do the join in spark so that we can use the complete processing power of spark?  If we use RDBMS for processing this complex query, then spark has to do very less processing.